# Bulma columns mobile overflowing body

Tags: css, bulma

I'm trying to use bulma columns but they are overflowing the body in mobile views. In the next picture you can see the white gap to the right of the screen. I inspected and the body tag is flush with the 'tomato' section's right border. However when the instance of columns appears it overflows the body tag and creates horizontal scrolling.

Thanks in advance for your help!

[image: Screenshot]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.6.2/css/bulma.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-3AB7yXWz4OeoZcPbieVW64vVXEwADiYyAEhwilzWsLw+9FgqpyjjStpPnpBO8o8S" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/stylesheets/main.css">
  <title>Buffalo Wings</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="bw-hero" style='display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center'>
    <h1 class='title is-bold' style="color: white">slider tbd</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="container">

    <div class="columns">
      <div class="column">
        <img src="assets/images/svg/the_chicken_wings_experts.svg" alt="The chicken wings experts">
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <h2 class="title has-text-centered">SELECCIONA TU PAÍS Y CIUDAD</h2>
        <div class="field is-grouped is-grouped-centered">
          <div class="control">
            <div class="select">
              <select>
              <option>País</option>
              <option>With options</option>
            </select>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="control">
            <div class="select">
              <select>
              <option>Ciudad</option>
              <option>With options</option>
            </select>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field has-text-centered">
          <input class="is-checkradio" id="saveLocationPreferences" type="checkbox" name="saveLocationPreferences" checked="checked">
          <label for="saveLocationPreferences">Recordar mi selección</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 7):

For avoid horizontal scrolling on mobile device change `viewport meta` tag in your `<head>` with this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1 maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

instead of :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: Is there any reason why this method is preferred instead of styling `overflow-x: hidden;` to the `body` tag? This seems to disable the capability for users to zoom.

Answer (score 6):

For me the solution is hiding horizontal overflow in the body, as such

```
body {
   overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

@sam-nzd offered an alternative solution, but it disables users capabilty to zoom. I'd love to know myself which is the better option.